# Does Android have an IDFV?

Tags: android, google-play-services, idfa, google-advertising-id

I would like to use the [IDFV](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor) feature on Android and I'm stuck in searching for a good alternatives. Can anyone suggest a good alternatives if it's available for Android it's really appreciating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's called [App set ID](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/app-set-id), the restrictions and functionality is very close to those of IDFV

Comment: Thank you for the answer @vik